# jQuery: Unable to select element by name which contain string followed by [..]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some elements which contain name=kra[0][category] , name=kra[1][category].. and follows.
But when i select this elements by name i am unable to do it.

my jquery code:

```
$("[name = kra[0][category]]").prop("disabled" , true);
```

Comment: If the name is "kra[0][category]" as a string, you must include the quotes in the jQuery selector: `$("[name='kra[0][category]']").prop("disabled", true);`  If the name is what kra[0][category] equals than you must get the value and put the value into the jquery selector as a string like so: `$("[name='" + kra[0][category] + "']").prop("disabled", true);`

Comment: no. not working @JeremyE.

Comment: Can you post the html code of the element that has `name=kra[0][category]`?

Comment: $("[name = 'kra[0][category]']").prop("disabled" , true);

Answer (score 0):

The following works (assuming it concerns an input element):

```
$("input[name='[kra[0][category]]']").prop("disabled" , true);
```

The name must be between quotes when it is not a single word.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you and `kra` is a javascript array you can try:

```
$('[name = "' + kra[0][category] + '"]').prop("disabled" , true);
```

Your array was IN the string, it has to be outside :)

Comment: no its not a array dude.. its name @ThatsEli

Comment: @varVijayShah Is the name kra[0][category]? Cause that looks/is an array.